# C# Threading, How to make a thread run a method with params?

Tags: c#, multithreading

is using global variables as params the only way or is there a more fashionate way to do it?

Comment: Using global variables as parameters to a thread is probably the single worst way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx) to start a thread with parameters.

Example:

```
Thread newThread = new Thread(myObj.DoMethod);
newThread.Start(parameter);
```

Although, I usually end up using lambdas

```
Thread newThread = new Thread(() => myObj.DoMethod(param1, param2, param3));
newThread.Start();
```

This can be more convenient because ParameterizedThreadStart takes a single `object` as a parameter. This is rarely what I want.

Comment: () => whats that macro? (dont know that from java)

Comment: The `=>` notation is a [lambda expression.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) It's a short way to write anonymous functions.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a closure using a simple `Action<T>` that then calls your method with parameters:

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    CallSomeMethod(someParam);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As root46 already answered, if working directly with threads then use [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h2f2459.aspx). But also have a look at [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) and [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) if you are working with .NET 4 or above.

Answer (score 0):

The more language agnostic way of doing this is that when the method can only take a single argument and you have more than one piece of data, create a new class with properties for each of the arguments that you want and then just pass an instance of that class.  (This is what you see done with the `EventArgs` objects related to event handling.)

Having said that, using closures from lambdas, as said by others, is a rather slick and easy way of doing things that tends to be more convenient in practice.